# QWindow Program on QT Creator won't run

Tags: qt-creator

I have made a program on Qt Creator which builds without errors. But when I try to run it, I get the following in my output pane. Can anyone please tell me what this means/how to fix this? I would appreciate any help.

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Invalid argument\n"
*** glibc detected *** /home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000060b580 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x733b6)[0x7ffff5d423b6]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7ffff5d472dc]
/home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave[0x405359]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7ffff5cedbfd]
/home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave[0x4042b9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00409000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9962314                            /home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave
00608000-00609000 r--p 00008000 08:03 9962314                            /home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave
00609000-0060a000 rw-p 00009000 08:03 9962314                            /home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave
0060a000-0062b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fffec000000-7fffec021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffec021000-7ffff0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff083c000-7ffff283d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff283d000-7ffff283f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806318                    /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ffff283f000-7ffff2a3f000 ---p 00002000 08:03 3806318                    /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ffff2a3f000-7ffff2a40000 r--p 00002000 08:03 3806318                    /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ffff2a40000-7ffff2a41000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 3806318                    /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ffff2a41000-7ffff2a5d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806425                    /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ffff2a5d000-7ffff2c5c000 ---p 0001c000 08:03 3806425                    /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ffff2c5c000-7ffff2c5d000 r--p 0001b000 08:03 3806425                    /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ffff2c5d000-7ffff2c5e000 rw-p 0001c000 08:03 3806425                    /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ffff2c5e000-7ffff2c85000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10747978                   /lib64/libexpat.so.1.5.2
7ffff2c85000-7ffff2e85000 ---p 00027000 08:03 10747978                   /lib64/libexpat.so.1.5.2
7ffff2e85000-7ffff2e87000 r--p 00027000 08:03 10747978                   /lib64/libexpat.so.1.5.2
7ffff2e87000-7ffff2e88000 rw-p 00029000 08:03 10747978                   /lib64/libexpat.so.1.5.2
7ffff2e88000-7ffff2e8c000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10748069                   /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7ffff2e8c000-7ffff308b000 ---p 00004000 08:03 10748069                   /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7ffff308b000-7ffff308c000 r--p 00003000 08:03 10748069                   /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7ffff308c000-7ffff308d000 rw-p 00004000 08:03 10748069                   /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7ffff308d000-7ffff30c2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10747968                   /lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
7ffff30c2000-7ffff32c1000 ---p 00035000 08:03 10747968                   /lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
7ffff32c1000-7ffff32c2000 r--p 00034000 08:03 10747968                   /lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
7ffff32c2000-7ffff32c3000 rw-p 00035000 08:03 10747968                   /lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
7ffff32c3000-7ffff32c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10748045                   /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff32c7000-7ffff34c6000 ---p 00004000 08:03 10748045                   /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff34c6000-7ffff34c7000 r--p 00003000 08:03 10748045                   /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff34c7000-7ffff34c8000 rw-p 00004000 08:03 10748045                   /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff34c8000-7ffff3605000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806790                    /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ffff3605000-7ffff3805000 ---p 0013d000 08:03 3806790                    /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ffff3805000-7ffff3806000 r--p 0013d000 08:03 3806790                    /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ffff3806000-7ffff380b000 rw-p 0013e000 08:03 3806790                    /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ffff380b000-7ffff381d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3807691                    /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ffff381d000-7ffff3a1c000 ---p 00012000 08:03 3807691                    /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ffff3a1c000-7ffff3a1d000 r--p 00011000 08:03 3807691                    /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ffff3a1d000-7ffff3a1e000 rw-p 00012000 08:03 3807691                    /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ffff3a1e000-7ffff3a53000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806497                    /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4
7ffff3a53000-7ffff3c53000 ---p 00035000 08:03 3806497                    /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4
7ffff3c53000-7ffff3c54000 r--p 00035000 08:03 3806497                    /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4
7ffff3c54000-7ffff3c55000 rw-p 00036000 08:03 3806497                    /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4
7ffff3c55000-7ffff3c57000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3808118                    /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
7ffff3c57000-7ffff3e56000 ---p 00002000 08:03 3808118                    /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
7ffff3e56000-7ffff3e57000 r--p 00001000 08:03 3808118                    /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
7ffff3e57000-7ffff3e58000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 3808118                    /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
7ffff3e58000-7ffff3e62000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3808106                    /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7ffff3e62000-7ffff4061000 ---p 0000a000 08:03 3808106                    /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7ffff4061000-7ffff4062000 r--p 00009000 08:03 3808106                    /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7ffff4062000-7ffff4063000 rw-p 0000a000 08:03 3808106                    /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7ffff4063000-7ffff4068000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3807689                    /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7ffff4068000-7ffff4267000 ---p 00005000 08:03 3807689                    /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7ffff4267000-7ffff4268000 r--p 00004000 08:03 3807689                    /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7ffff4268000-7ffff4269000 rw-p 00005000 08:03 3807689                    /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7ffff4269000-7ffff4271000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3808122                    /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
7ffff4271000-7ffff4470000 ---p 00008000 08:03 3808122                    /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
7ffff4470000-7ffff4471000 r--p 00007000 08:03 3808122                    /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
7ffff4471000-7ffff4472000 rw-p 00008000 08:03 3808122                    /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
7ffff4472000-7ffff447c000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3807681                    /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7ffff447c000-7ffff467b000 ---p 0000a000 08:03 3807681                    /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7ffff467b000-7ffff467c000 r--p 00009000 08:03 3807681                    /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7ffff467c000-7ffff467d000 rw-p 0000a000 08:03 3807681                    /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7ffff467d000-7ffff468c000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3807981                    /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6.1.0
7ffff468c000-7ffff488b000 ---p 0000f000 08:03 3807981                    /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6.1.0
7ffff488b000-7ffff488c000 r--p 0000e000 08:03 3807981                    /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6.1.0
7ffff488c000-7ffff488d000 rw-p 0000f000 08:03 3807981                    /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6.1.0
7ffff488d000-7ffff48a4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806320                    /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
7ffff48a4000-7ffff4aa4000 ---p 00017000 08:03 3806320                    /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
7ffff4aa4000-7ffff4aa5000 r--p 00017000 08:03 3806320                    /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
7ffff4aa5000-7ffff4aa6000 rw-p 00018000 08:03 3806320                    /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
7ffff4aa6000-7ffff4aaa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff4aaa000-7ffff4ab1000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806608                    /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6.0.1
7ffff4ab1000-7ffff4cb1000 ---p 00007000 08:03 3806608                    /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6.0.1
7ffff4cb1000-7ffff4cb2000 r--p 00007000 08:03 3806608                    /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6.0.1
7ffff4cb2000-7ffff4cb3000 rw-p 00008000 08:03 3806608                    /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6.0.1
7ffff4cb3000-7ffff4d01000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10748064                   /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff4d01000-7ffff4f01000 ---p 0004e000 08:03 10748064                   /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff4f01000-7ffff4f02000 r--p 0004e000 08:03 10748064                   /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff4f02000-7ffff4f03000 rw-p 0004f000 08:03 10748064                   /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff4f03000-7ffff4f04000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff4f04000-7ffff4f88000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806341                    /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.6.2
7ffff4f88000-7ffff5188000 ---p 00084000 08:03 3806341                    /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.6.2
7ffff5188000-7ffff518d000 r--p 00084000 08:03 3806341                    /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.6.2
7ffff518d000-7ffff518e000 rw-p 00089000 08:03 3806341                    /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.6.2
7ffff518e000-7ffff51a4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10748027                   /lib64/libz.so.1.2.5
7ffff51a4000-7ffff53a4000 ---p 00016000 08:03 10748027                   /lib64/libz.so.1.2.5
7ffff53a4000-7ffff53a5000 r--p 00016000 08:03 10748027                   /lib64/libz.so.1.2.5
7ffff53a5000-7ffff53a6000 rw-p 00017000 08:03 10748027                   /lib64/libz.so.1.2.5
7ffff53a6000-7ffff53cf000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806339                    /usr/lib64/libpng14.so.14.4.0
7ffff53cf000-7ffff55ce000 ---p 00029000 08:03 3806339                    /usr/lib64/libpng14.so.14.4.0
7ffff55ce000-7ffff55cf000 r--p 00028000 08:03 3806339                    /usr/lib64/libpng14.so.14.4.0
7ffff55cf000-7ffff55d0000 rw-p 00029000 08:03 3806339                    /usr/lib64/libpng14.so.14.4.0
7ffff55d0000-7ffff56c0000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10748033                   /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff56c0000-7ffff58bf000 ---p 000f0000 08:03 10748033                   /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff58bf000-7ffff58c0000 r--p 000ef000 08:03 10748033                   /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff58c0000-7ffff58c1000 rw-p 000f0000 08:03 10748033                   /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.0
7ffff58c1000-7ffff58c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff58c2000-7ffff58ca000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10747943                   /lib64/librt-2.11.3.so
7ffff58ca000-7ffff5ac9000 ---p 00008000 08:03 10747943                   /lib64/librt-2.11.3.so
7ffff5ac9000-7ffff5aca000 r--p 00007000 08:03 10747943                   /lib64/librt-2.11.3.so
7ffff5aca000-7ffff5acb000 rw-p 00008000 08:03 10747943                   /lib64/librt-2.11.3.so
7ffff5acb000-7ffff5acd000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10747919                   /lib64/libdl-2.11.3.so
7ffff5acd000-7ffff5ccd000 ---p 00002000 08:03 10747919                   /lib64/libdl-2.11.3.so
7ffff5ccd000-7ffff5cce000 r--p 00002000 08:03 10747919                   /lib64/libdl-2.11.3.so
7ffff5cce000-7ffff5ccf000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 10747919                   /lib64/libdl-2.11.3.so
7ffff5ccf000-7ffff5e33000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10747913                   /lib64/libc-2.11.3.so
7ffff5e33000-7ffff6032000 ---p 00164000 08:03 10747913                   /lib64/libc-2.11.3.so
7ffff6032000-7ffff6036000 r--p 00163000 08:03 10747913                   /lib64/libc-2.11.3.so
7ffff6036000-7ffff6037000 rw-p 00167000 08:03 10747913                   /lib64/libc-2.11.3.so
7ffff6037000-7ffff603c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff603c000-7ffff6051000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10748067                   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff6051000-7ffff6250000 ---p 00015000 08:03 10748067                   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff6250000-7ffff6251000 r--p 00014000 08:03 10748067                   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff6251000-7ffff6252000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 10748067                   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff6252000-7ffff62a8000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10747921                   /lib64/libm-2.11.3.so
7ffff62a8000-7ffff64a7000 ---p 00056000 08:03 10747921                   /lib64/libm-2.11.3.so
7ffff64a7000-7ffff64a8000 r--p 00055000 08:03 10747921                   /lib64/libm-2.11.3.so
7ffff64a8000-7ffff64a9000 rw-p 00056000 08:03 10747921                   /lib64/libm-2.11.3.so
7ffff64a9000-7ffff6594000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806566                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
7ffff6594000-7ffff6793000 ---p 000eb000 08:03 3806566                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
7ffff6793000-7ffff679b000 r--p 000ea000 08:03 3806566                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
7ffff679b000-7ffff679d000 rw-p 000f2000 08:03 3806566                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
7ffff679d000-7ffff67b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff67b2000-7ffff67c9000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10747939                   /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so
7ffff67c9000-7ffff69c9000 ---p 00017000 08:03 10747939                   /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so
7ffff69c9000-7ffff69ca000 r--p 00017000 08:03 10747939                   /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so
7ffff69ca000-7ffff69cb000 rw-p 00018000 08:03 10747939                   /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so
7ffff69cb000-7ffff69cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff69cf000-7ffff6c59000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3808046                    /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.7.1
7ffff6c59000-7ffff6e58000 ---p 0028a000 08:03 3808046                    /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.7.1
7ffff6e58000-7ffff6e63000 r--p 00289000 08:03 3808046                    /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.7.1
7ffff6e63000-7ffff6e64000 rw-p 00294000 08:03 3808046                    /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.7.1
7ffff6e64000-7ffff6e65000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff6e65000-7ffff78b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3808607                    /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.7.1
7ffff78b8000-7ffff7ab8000 ---p 00a53000 08:03 3808607                    /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.7.1
7ffff7ab8000-7ffff7af7000 r--p 00a53000 08:03 3808607                    /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.7.1
7ffff7af7000-7ffff7afe000 rw-p 00a92000 08:03 3808607                    /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.7.1
7ffff7afe000-7ffff7b01000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7b01000-7ffff7bd9000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3806311                    /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2.0.0
7ffff7bd9000-7ffff7dd8000 ---p 000d8000 08:03 3806311                    /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2.0.0
7ffff7dd8000-7ffff7dde000 r--p 000d7000 08:03 3806311                    /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2.0.0
7ffff7dde000-7ffff7ddf000 rw-p 000dd000 08:03 3806311                    /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2.0.0
7ffff7ddf000-7ffff7dfd000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10747906                   /lib64/ld-2.11.3.so
7ffff7fcc000-7ffff7fdc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7fe8000-7ffff7ff8000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 4435                       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
7ffff7ff8000-7ffff7ff9000 rw-s 81000000 00:05 4435                       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
7ffff7ff9000-7ffff7ffa000 r--s 80000000 00:05 4435                       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 0001d000 08:03 10747906                   /lib64/ld-2.11.3.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 0001e000 08:03 10747906                   /lib64/ld-2.11.3.so
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

main.cpp:

```
  #include <QtGui>
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <qlineedit.h>
    #include "ui_wave.h"
    #include <QString>
    #include <QObject>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <sched.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <getopt.h>
    #include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "wave.h"
    using namespace std;

    static const char *device = "plughw:0,0";             //   playback device
    static snd_pcm_format_t format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16;   //  sample format- change to 24-bit
    static unsigned int rate = 96000;                      //  stream rate
    static unsigned int channels = 128;                   //   count of channels
    static unsigned int buffer_time = 500000;               // ring buffer length in us
    static unsigned int period_time = 100000;               // period time in us
    static double freq;                                     // sinusoidal wave frequency in Hz
    static int verbose = 0;                                 // verbose flag
    static int resample = 1;                                // enable alsa-lib resampling
    static int period_event = 0;                // produce poll event after each period
    static snd_pcm_sframes_t buffer_size;
    static snd_pcm_sframes_t period_size;
    static snd_output_t *output = NULL;
    static double ampl;
    static snd_pcm_t *h;
    static bool isTrue;

   ....

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

            struct option long_option[] =
            {
                    {"help", 0, NULL, 'h'},
                    {"device", 1, NULL, 'D'},
                    {"rate", 1, NULL, 'r'},
                    {"channels", 1, NULL, 'c'},
                    {"frequency", 1, NULL, 'f'},
                    {"buffer", 1, NULL, 'b'},
                    {"period", 1, NULL, 'p'},
                    {"method", 1, NULL, 'm'},
                    {"format", 1, NULL, 'o'},
                    {"verbose", 1, NULL, 'v'},
                    {"noresample", 1, NULL, 'n'},
                    {"pevent", 1, NULL, 'e'},
                    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0},
            };
            int err, morehelp;
            snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hwparams;
            snd_pcm_sw_params_t *swparams;
            int method = 0;
            short int *samp;
            snd_pcm_t *h;
            snd_pcm_channel_area_t *area;
            snd_pcm_t *handle = (snd_pcm_t*) h;
            unsigned char *samples  = (unsigned char*) samp;
            unsigned int chn;
            snd_pcm_channel_area_t *areas = (snd_pcm_channel_area_t*) area;

            snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&hwparams);
            snd_pcm_sw_params_alloca(&swparams);


            err = snd_output_stdio_attach(&output, stdout, 0);
            if (err < 0) {
                    printf("Output failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
                    return 0;
            }
    //    cout<<"Playback device is %s  "<<","<< device);
       //     cout<<"Stream parameters are %iHz, %s, %i channels  "<<","<< rate<<","<< snd_pcm_format_name(format), channels;
       //     cout<<"Sine wave rate is %.4fHz  "<<","<< freq;
        //    cout<<"Using transfer method: %s  "<<","<< transfer_methods[method].name;

            if ((err = snd_pcm_open(&h, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)) < 0) {
                    printf("Playback open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
                    return 0;
            }

            if ((err = set_hwparams(h, hwparams, transfer_methods[method].access)) < 0) {
                    printf("Setting of hwparams failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if ((err = set_swparams(h, swparams)) < 0) {
                    printf("Setting of swparams failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if (verbose > 0)
                    snd_pcm_dump(h, output);

            samp = new short int [period_size * channels * snd_pcm_format_physical_width(format)];


            if (samp == NULL) {
                    printf("Not enough memory\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            area = new snd_pcm_channel_area_t [channels, sizeof(snd_pcm_channel_area_t)];
            if (area == NULL) {
                    printf("Not enough memory\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            for (chn = 0; chn < channels; chn++) {
                    area[chn].addr = samp;
                    area[chn].first = chn * snd_pcm_format_physical_width(format);
                    area[chn].step = channels * snd_pcm_format_physical_width(format);
            }

           err = write_loop(h, samp, area);
            if (err < 0)
                    printf("Transfer failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));

            delete(area);
            delete(samp);
            snd_pcm_close(h);
            return 0;


    QApplication a(argc, argv);
        wave w;
        w.show();

        return a.exec();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some source code would be nice.
It looks like you're trying to delete something twice.

Comment: so sorry. my main.cpp has been added above to my question

Answer (score 0):

If you cant catch this problem in the debug then you can analyze the backtrace you just posted to find which function in your program caused this.  first do nm ./NameOfYourProgram to get the list of symbols.  The list of symbols also displays the address of each function.  The addresses in your backtrace will be greater or equal to the symbol addresses.  The functions you need to look at in your backtrace are:

/home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave[0x405359]
...
/home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave[0x4042b9]

the addresses here are: 0x405359 and 0x4042b9.  You can then step through the function you found and stop at 0x405359 and you will find the exact line in your code where the exception occured.

Comment: Actually I used the debug to find the line and it has a problem with the line:   delete(area); at the end of my code. But this line must be there to empty the space. I'm not sure how to fix it or what is wrong with this line.

Comment: You can start by commenting most of your code and just leave the new a delete and see if that works.  If so then its happening in the code you commented.  In that case then gradually uncomment your cod until you find the faulty code.

Answer (score 0):

This important line is this:

> glibc detected * * * /home/test/Documents/Wave-build-desktop/Wave: ***double free*** or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000060b580 ***

Comment: Actually that message does not indicate where the problem is most of the time specially in a Qt multi-threaded application. It means that the system is trying to release dynamic memory that has already been released.  This most likely links to a dereferencing event in Qt.

Comment: for example:  msgByte=(char*)malloc(theSize);  free(msgByte);  free(msgByte);

Comment: I do have something similar in my code except that it uses new and delete in stead of malloc and free. (as shown below). I have also edited my question(at the beginning of the page) to include my main function in main.cpp.       samp = new short int [period_size * channels * snd_pcm_format_physical_width(format)];   area = new snd_pcm_channel_area_t [channels, sizeof(snd_pcm_channel_area_t)];                                             delete(area);
            delete(samp);
            snd_pcm_close(h);
            return 0;

Comment: did you try commenting everything between the new and the delete as I mentioned earlier.  If this gets rid of the error then gradually uncomment the code until the error appears again and that should pinpoint the problem.  Get back to me with the results.